# Cast to a Specific Type at Runtime

Tags: c#, types, casting

I need to cast to a specific Type at Runtime.

How it works, and looks like - now:

```
Customer test = (Customer)entityBase.GetType().GetProperty("Customer").GetValue(entityBase, null);
```

The Customer as String, where I need for `GetProperty()`, isn't written like that *directly*, it comes from a Variable, that changes always. I just wrote "Customer", for comprehension purposes.

What I want now is the same, but without telling, that its a Customer or any Type.

```
Placeholder test = (Placeholder)entityBase.GetType().GetProperty("That Changes, thats fine").GetValue(entityBase, null);
```

Cause it could also be something like that:

```
Order test = (Order)entityBase.GetType().GetProperty("That Changes, thats fine").GetValue(entityBase, null);
```

I tried things like `businnesObject = Activator.CreateInstance(type);`

Hope someone has a small solution for this

Comment: You might need this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264736.aspx

Comment: please clearly tell what is your need? just conversion or creating object at runtime?

Comment: I got it now, shamp00s answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Customer` and `Order` both inherit from `System.Object`, so you can just use

```
Object test = entityBase.GetType().GetProperty("That Changes, thats fine").GetValue(entityBase, null);
```

Comment: That would mean they would be able to access methods in `Customer` or `Order` depending on what they actually are.

Comment: @AshBurlaczenko: But in order to access those methods, you'd need to know at compile-time which type you're interested in anyway...

Answer (score 3):

If you need to do all checks at runtime you could cast it to `dynamic`. With this you lose all intellisense and compile time checks, but I thing this is what you intended.

```
dynamic test = entityBase.GetType().GetProperty("Customer").GetValue(entityBase, null);
```

Answer (score 1):

if your purpose is to create object of some class at runtime,

```
Type assemblyType = Type.GetType("yournamespace.class,yournamespace");

YourClass objYourClass=(YourClass)Activator.CreateInstance(assemblyType);
```

the corresponding dll of your namespace must reside inside bin folder.